# How to separate two multi-column `<div>`s that are connected together?

Tags: html, css

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zouse1rd/) I created showing how the code looks. How would I go about giving these `<div>`s a gap between them without an element falling below another?

```css
.main-content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: -10px;
  height: 315px;
}

.main-content>h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.ul-main>li {
  display: block;
}

.related-content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.video {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-content'>
  <h2>GTR FACTS</h2>
  <div class='main-list'>
    <ul class='ul-main'>
      <li>The GT-R is the world’s fastest accelerating production four-seater</li>
      <li>It’s the fastest four-seat production car around the Nurburgring</li>
      <li>Nissan GT-R engines are hand built by race engineers</li>
      <li>The Nissan GT-R has near 50:50 weight distribution</li>
      <li>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='related-content'>
  <div class='video'>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PAjD4GFi3Ko" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using float, reduce each elements `width` and add a `margin` to one of them. I'd recommend using flexbox or grid for this layout though.

Comment: display: flex with a left margin on the right column or a right margin on the left

Answer (score 1):

If your element is reserving `50%` of the width there will be no space between of them.

one of the div's have to be less than 50% and Using `display: flex` with `justify-content: space-between` will keep elements apart of each other.

Check this code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-content {
  width: 45%;
  background: #232323;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: -10px;
  height: 315px;
}

.main-content>h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.ul-main>li {
  display: block;
}

.related-content {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.video {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class='main-content'>
    <h2>GTR FACTS</h2>
    <div class='main-list'>
      <ul class='ul-main'>
        <li>The GT-R is the world’s fastest accelerating production four-seater</li>
        <li>It’s the fastest four-seat production car around the Nurburgring</li>
        <li>Nissan GT-R engines are hand built by race engineers</li>
        <li>The Nissan GT-R has near 50:50 weight distribution</li>
        <li>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='related-content'>
    <div class='video'>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PAjD4GFi3Ko" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```